# Unable to read "Binary (application/octet-stream)" file in python?

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning

I am trying to read data files from CIFAR-10 data set. I have downloaded it but I am unable to read the files. 
The code I am using to read the file.

```
def unpickle(file):
    print(file)
    import pickle
    fo = open(file, 'rb')
    dict = cPickle.load(fo)
    fo.close()
    return dict
    file = 'data_batch_1'
```

It is showing error"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "basiccnn.py", line 28, in <module>
data1 = unpickle(file)
File "basiccnn.py", line 23, in unpickle
dict = cPickle.load(fo)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position    6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: What has lead you to believe that you have a pickle file?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html

Comment: You downloaded the Python version, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Since your getting:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position    6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

You seem to have an encoding issue. According to [pickle.loads()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.load), the default encoding *ASCII* is used which is likely why your getting that error. Setting *encoding* to *"bytes"* fixes the issue:

```
data = pickle.load(fo, encoding='bytes')
```

---

Two more things:

1. `cPickle` was renamed to `_pickle` in Python 3, but you should really just use `pickle`.
2. It's terrible practice to name variables the same as built-in types. [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) is used by the dictionary data type. Use some other ambiguous name such as `data` instead.